# Read filenames in a directory with AutoHotkey

Tags: directory, autohotkey

I am looking for a way to read a folder and save each filename to a variable. So far this is what I have

```
Loop,C:\My Documents\Notes\*
```

In my notes directory I have pdf files. I want to read the directory and save the filename  "Homework1.pdf" to a variable then move the file itself to another directory. On the next loop it will pick up the next pdf document "Test.pdf" etc. This should loop until every pdf has been moved.

I know I could use FileMove but the samples show that you have to provide the specific filename to move. How can I adjust this to move each pdf file one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass creating a list to parse (assuming you don't need the variables for anything else) and use the built-in variables `A_LoopFileFullPath` and `A_LoopFileName` to accomplish this.

```
Loop, C:\My Documents\Notes\*.pdf
    FileCopy, % A_LoopFileFullPath, C:\NewPath\%A_LoopFileName%
```

EDIT: Try this for a preview of your result

```
Loop, C:\My Documents\Notes\*.pdf
    Msgbox % A_LoopFileFullPath "`nC:\NewPath\" A_LoopFileName
```

Comment: Thanks. The built-in variables help but will I have to set A_LoopFileFullPath and A_LoopFileName to "" at the end of the loop in order to get the next filename?

Comment: No, those will be done automatically. I'll put some code so you can preview.

Answer (score 2):

```
FileList =
Loop, C:\My Documents\Notes\*
   FileList = %FileList%%A_LoopFileName%`n
Loop, parse, FileList, `n
   FileMove, %A_LoopField%, C:\NewLocation
```

Original source: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm