# Powershell script with response and no window?

Tags: powershell, autohotkey

I want to run a command in PowerShell and use the response in AutoHotkey. I have found a lot of information on how to run a PowerShell script, but none saying how I can use the response from it in AutoHotkey.

I have tried this:

```
MsgBox % ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -noProfile -nologo dir").StdOut.ReadAll()
```

But this still flashes a window for a very brief time. I loop this command for every 25ms, so letting a window blink that often is not a valid solution.

Edit:

Ended up with this as the simplest solution:

```
cmd = powershell.exe -command "(Get-Process -Id " %pid% ").Threads[1].WaitReason"
shell := setup()
    Loop {
        string := shell.exec(cmd).stdout.readall()
        ...}


setup() {
    detecthiddenwindows on
    run %comspec% /k ,, hide useerrorlevel, pid
    winwait ahk_pid %pid%,, 10
    DllCall("AttachConsole", "uint", pid)
    con := DllCall("CreateFile"
        , "str", "CONOUT$", "uint", 0xC0000000, "uint", 7, "uint", 0, "uint", 3, "uint", 0, "uint", 0)

    oshell := comobjcreate("wscript.shell")

    return oshell
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to run a PowerShell script without displaying a window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802836/8890345)

Comment: @NathanMills Read it, but is it possible to pass the response back to AHK when using this PsRun script?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297699/hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec

Comment: @JohnLBevan: The linked post is helpful for _VBScript_ code; a native AHK approach is demonstrated below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Using AHK (AutoHotkey) with an external PowerShell process is ill-suited to a task that must run *every 25ms*, as you've discovered yourself - there's too much processing overhead.
If getting a directory listing is all that is needed, you can do that with built-in AHK features, using the [`Loop` command for files](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17738014/45375).

The **solution below generally demonstrates how to run a console program**:

- **hidden** (no flashing windows)
- **synchronously** (wait for it exit)
- with its **output captured**

from AHK.

---

You can't use [`ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ateytk4a%28v%3dvs.85%29) to run a console application *hidden*.

Conversely, while you can use [`RunWait`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) to run hidden, you cannot use it to *capture (console) output*.

The **workaround** is to:

- Use `RunWait`.
- Add an output redirection to a (temporary) *file* to your console-program invocation.
- Read that file's content with `FileRead` afterwards (and delete the temp. file).

```
; Get a temporary file path
tempFile := A_Temp "\" DllCall("GetCurrentProcessId") ".txt"                           ; "

; Run the console program hidden, redirecting its output to
; the temp. file (with a program other than powershell.exe or cmd.exe,
; prepend %ComSpec% /c; use 2> to redirect error output), and wait for it to exit.
RunWait, powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -noProfile dir > %tempFile%,, Hide

; Read the temp file into a variable and then delete it.
FileRead, content, %tempFile%
FileDelete, %tempFile%

; Display the result.
MsgBox % content
```

Comment: It does work, but doing it 40 times a second puts 50% CPU load :/ I guess I have to look for another language to do this with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was not all that was needed (The actual command is in my edited post), and for this there seems to be no native approach. I also added an edit that shows a solution for this that doesn't require files. I have accepted your answer as it showed me that I need to use another tool for this task.

Comment: Thanks, @JonnyLee - that's a pretty sophisticated solution and I encourage you to  post it as a self-answer to a _new_ question focused on the performance aspect (a persistent, hidden console window that can be used for repeated console-program invocations, if I understand correctly) so that it's more easily discoverable.